# Updating and deleting multiple images using Formset in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django so please forgive any silly mistakes in my code. I have made a post with multiple images using FBV. it works perfectly fine and does its job of adding multiple images to a post. Now I am working on editing the Post however I am having issues with editing the post I get the below error.

```
AttributeError at /gangsters/edit/Scarface-the-story-of-Al-Capone/
'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/gangsters/edit/Scarface-the-story-of-Al-Capone
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

A brief description of my models Lets say I am trying to make this web-app that allows users to write about Gangsters (more like the post model)from around the world and from different time periods. There are 2 models. Gangsters and GangMembers. GangMember has a foreign_key to Gangster

my models are as below

```
class Gangster(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    gangster_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    history = models.TextField()
    gangster_image = models.ImageField()
    # there are more attributes like "Post-like but ignoring them as they are not relevant here"

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title) #for SEO on google searches
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Gangmember(models.Model): 
    gangster = models.ForeignKey(Gangster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ganglord")
    gangmember_image= models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True, default='')
    gangmember_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    brief_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
```

below is my **gangster_edit views.py**

```
@login_required
def gangster_edit(request, slug):
    gangster = get_object_or_404(Gangster, slug=slug)
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Gangmember, fields=('gangmember_image', 'gangmember_name', 'gangmember_description'), extra=7, max_num=7)
    if gangster.user != request.user:
        raise Http404()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GangsterEditForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=gangster)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
            data = GangMember.objects.filter(gangster=gangster)
            for index, f in enumerate(formset):
                if f.cleaned_data:
                    if f.cleaned_data['id'] is None:
                        photo = GangMember(gangster=gangster, image=f.cleaned_data.get('image'), image_title=f.cleaned_data.get('image_title'),
                                     image_description=f.cleaned_data.get('image_description'))
                        photo.save()
                    elif (f.cleaned_data['image'], f.cleaned_data['image_title'], f.cleaned_data['image_description']) is False:
                        photo = Gangmember.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))
                        photo.delete()
                    else:
                        photo = Gangmember(gangster=gangster, image=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_image'), image_title=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_name'),
                                     image_description=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_description'))
                        d = GangMember.objects.get(id=data[index].id)
                        d.gangmember_image=photo.gangmember_image,
                        d.gangmember_name=photo.gangmember_name,
                        d.gangmember_description=photo.gangmember_description
                        d.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(gangster.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = GangsterEditForm(instance=gangster)
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Gangmember.objects.filter(gangster=gangster))
    context = {'form': form, 'gangster': gangster, 'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'gangsters/gangster_edit.html', context)
```

I am sorry if the question is too long. Again my ***gangster_edit*** view is not working and giving an AttributeError error. The error detail is pasted above. If you have read till here, thank you so much for trying to help me solve this

TraceBack Error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 02, 2018 - 22:22:03
Django version 1.11, using settings 'Khal.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.


[02/May/2018 22:22:46] "GET /gangsters/samir/al-capone-from-chicago/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31213
[02/May/2018 22:22:49] "GET /gangsters/edit/al-capone-from-chicago/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18773
[{'gangmember_image': <ImageFieldFile: images/3.jpg>, 'gangmember_name': 'A', 'brief_description': 'This is A You will love A', 'id': <Gangmember: Al Capone from Chicago Image>}, {'gangmember_image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: B.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'gangmember_name': 'B', 'brief_description': 'This is B
You will love B', 'id': None}, {'gangmember_image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: C.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'gangmember_name': 'C', 'brief_description': 'Thi
s is C You will love C', 'id': None}, {'gangmember_image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: D.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'gangmember_name': 'D', 'image_description
': 'This is D You will love D', 'id': None}, {'gangmember_image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: E.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'gangmember_name': 'E.', 'brief_description': 'This is E You will love E', 'id': None}, {}, {}]
Internal Server Error: /gangsters/edit/al-capone-from-chicago/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Documents\gangsters\views.py", line 144, in gangster_edit
    d.save()
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 900, in _save_table
    for f in non_pks]
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 900, in <listcomp>
    for f in non_pks]
  File "C:\Users\Samir\Miniconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 295, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'
[02/May/2018 22:23:28] "POST /gangsters/edit/Scarface-the-story-of-Al-Capone
```

/ HTTP/1.1" 500 112934

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? It might give some more clues as to whereabouts in the code the issue is occurring.

Comment: @WillKeeling thank you so much for looking into this, I have added the traceback, I am still learning Django so please forgive any silly mistakes

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is possibly because `Prep.gangmember_image` is not referencing an image (referencing a tuple), If you could also post the code for `Prep` I may be able to confirm that.

Comment: @WillKeeling  I have changed the code as per your advise. I believe that the else code below may have a error. I can't figure what though 
`else:
                        photo = Gangmember(gangster=gangster, image=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_image'), image_title=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_name'),
                                     image_description=f.cleaned_data.get('gangmember_description'))
                        d = .....
                        d.save()`